# Replication log reader agent not running - accidently deleted job

Tags: sql-server, replication

When I look in the Replication Monitor, I see that my Log Reader Agent is not running.
I right click on a publication, and click 'View Log Reader Agent Status' and it says "The proces was successfully stopped"

If i press Start, i get the following message....
It's possible i *could* of deleted the job 'NAVISIONUPGRADE-Navision4-1' by mistake yesterday... How can i re-create it / what does it do?

```
TITLE: View Log Reader Agent Status
------------------------------

The agent could not be started.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ReplUtilitiesErrorSR&EvtID=CantStartAgent&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The specified @job_name ('NAVISIONUPGRADE-Navision4-1') does not exist. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 14262)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=08.00.0760&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=14262&LinkId=20476
```

Comment: do you have any publications setup? are your subscribers getting updates?  which sever is running the distribution database?

Comment: yes, there are 3 publications. the subscribers are not getting updates. the subscriber is the distributor as far as i'm aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleted and then re-creating the publication.